# Why is jQuery not working in this wordpress plugin?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am pretty new to Wordpress. I have a plugin that I created and is working fine, except that when I try to do a simple jQuery ready function inside an included javascript file it is not seeing jQuery and I am getting an undefined error. I am doing this before I include the HTML file content.

Here is the code I am using to load the script (which is loading the js file just fine)

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_references_scripts');
function admin_references_scripts() {
    //Add CSS Files
    wp_enqueue_style('admin-references-style', plugins_url('/css/admin-references.css', __FILE__ ));
    wp_enqueue_style('admin-references-craftmap', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/craftmap.css');

    //Add JS files
    wp_register_script('admin-references-js', plugins_url('/js/admin-references.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-draggable'));
    wp_enqueue_script('admin-references-js');

    //Add the panel to the post type
    add_meta_box('admin-references-control', 'Admin References', 'admin_references_meta', 'admin_references', 'advanced', 'high');
}
```

And the admin-references.js file looks simply like this

```
$(function() {
    alert('here');
});
```

Here are my questions/problems

1. The wp_register_script call above should automatically make sure jquery is in there right?
2. Is there somewhere else in my plugin I should load jQuery?
3. Is it possible some other plugin is killing jquery?
4. I need the draggable jQuery UI functionality. Can I get this with what I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/wp-admin/load-scripts.php` is a wp-admin call, not a front-end one.

Are you trying to do your jQuery in wp-admin or in the front (theme) ?

Have you checked you're running jQuery in no conflict mode..

aka, it should be:

`jQuery(function() {
    alert('here');
});`

Comment: This plugin is basically a custom post type, so its in wp-admin. Sorry should have mentioned that. As far as the $ or jQuery goes, I have always used $ for that. Maybe I cant do that while in wordpress though? I can tell you that using $ is not whats causing the problem because I cant even reference an element like `$("#blah")`

Comment: Okay, nm I think it is because I was using $. Changing it to jQuery fixed the problem. So can I not use $ in wordpress?

Comment: WordPress uses jQuery in 'no conflict mode' which means you can't just use `$` to start doing things, this is to prevent conflicting with other javascript libraries etc..

Comment: Great thanks for your help! I figured it was something stupid. At least now I know.